# Why are the questions not coming one at a time? And why are they on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, promt, answer):
        self.promt = promt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [

    "What color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Orange\n\n",
    "What is my name?\n(a) ES\n (b) HG\n\n",
    "What is a currency?\n(a) Dollar\n (b) Lubby\n\n"
]


questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "a")
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question_prompts)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + " correct")

run_test(questions)
```

**The output is like this:**

```
['What color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Orange\n\n', 'What is my name?\n(a) ES\n (b) HG\n\n', 'What is a currency?\n(a) Dollar\n (b) Lubby\n\n']
```

**Why is the '\n' not working in this case? And how to make it work? And also, how do to make it one question at a time rather than all 3 at once?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just change `question_prompts` to `question.promt` in `input()`

```
class Question:
    def __init__(self, promt, answer):
        self.promt = promt
        self.answer = answer


question_prompts = [

    "What color are apples?\n(a) Red\n(b) Orange\n\n",
    "What is my name?\n(a) ES\n (b) HG\n\n",
    "What is a currency?\n(a) Dollar\n (b) Lubby\n\n"
]


questions = [
    Question(question_prompts[0], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[1], "a"),
    Question(question_prompts[2], "a")
]

def run_test(questions):
    score = 0
    for question in questions:
        answer = input(question.promt)
        if answer == question.answer:
            score += 1
    print("You got " + str(score) + "/" + str(len(questions)) + " correct")

run_test(questions)
```